# Get active page with subfolder in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for a method in .NET that will allow me to get the path of the current page, with any sub folders on the application. For example

localhost:3832/Admin/AdminTest.aspx returns Admin/AdminTest.aspx

localhost:3832/Test.aspx returns Test.aspx

http://www.deployed.com/Application/Admin/AdminTest.aspx returns Admin/AdminTest.aspx

Any ideas what method I can use for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a summary of the path options along with descriptions and example paths:

[Making Sense of ASP.NET Paths](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths)

Answer (score 0):

Try

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;